# PHP Reflection using an XML file

Tags: php, xml, reflection

I would like to create a PHP object from an XML file using Reflection Classes.

Is there any API that convert a PHP object (attributes, methods) to XML?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at PEAR's [XML_Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/redirected)